# Fragment after fragment in android

Tags: android, android-fragments, containers

I have a question that whenever i open a new fragment from another fragment it open up but when i come back by back button then why does it holds the background view of the previous fragment, if i add this piece of code to that fragment  if

```
(container != null) {
        container.removeAllViews();
    }
```

then it gets out on whole screen where i want it to be under the toolbar, it gets out of it and toolbar is not shown and sometimes app stops also.
I am a newbie to fragments so please answer my question in a calm and detailed way.
I have added a flow of how screens are appearing and this are fragments except first one,when it comes to 2nd again that time the screen looks partially like another.[image: this is the flow of all the screens][image: this is the screen when flow goes from fourth to second fragment, partial scrren visibility problem as i want to show the background fully only and not the table layout onewhich is appearing over it]

I use this code to add fragments on click of buttons

```
 Addhearingnewfrag fragment = new Addhearingnewfrag();
            FragmentManager fragmentManager = getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager();
            FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
            fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.contentFragment, fragment);
            fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack(null);
            fragmentTransaction.commit();
        }
    });
```

Comment: Do you want to remove the previous fragment so that it's not visible when you go back?

Comment: It depends on the way you "add"or "replace" the fragment to your main container. if you use "add" a new fragment is added to the previous fragment but if you are using replace it will replace the previous fragment with the new one.

Comment: Can you show your complete code?

Comment: @SaNtoRiaN please see my updated question.

Comment: @sachinnarang see the updated question please

Comment: Add the code you use to add fragments to the question.

Comment: i had added it,please see the updated one now

Comment: If you do no want to maintain fragments in backstack then remove  fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack(null); -> Because of this whenever you click back button , old fragment gets rendered. Might be that is the reason.

Comment: @Tasneem i want maintain them just as we click back and goes to previousactivity and then again on back on previous activity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess the problem beacuse you are using wrong fragment manager. If you open fragment from another fragment you should use

`getChildFragmentManager()`

instead of

`getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager()`

**UPDATE**

```
public class MyActivity implements Activity implements ChangeFragListener{

public interface ChangeFragListener{
     change(String id);
}            

@Override
public void change(String id){
  ...
  if(id.equals("addxx")){
            Addhearingnewfrag fragment = new Addhearingnewfrag();
            FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
            FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
            fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.contentFragment, fragment);
            fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack(null);
            fragmentTransaction.commit();
        }
    });
  }
}

}
```

**XFRagment.java**

```
public XFragment extends Fragment{
   private ChangeFragListener listener;

   protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        listener = (ChangeFragListener)getActivity();
   }

@Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {

btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
{
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v)
    {
       listener.change("fromOtherId");
    }
});

    }
}
```

You can use this interface in other fragments too. You shouldn't directly replace fragment from other fragment unless One is another's child.

**UPDATE - 2**

After review the project the main problem is because of fragment container.For example; you add home fragment to `R.id.frame`. But you replace other fragments to `R.id.drawer_layout`. And `R.id.drawer_layout` is reference to your Navigation Drawer not fragment container.

Moreover, `R.id.frame` does not looking like as fragment container. It has view components. Here there are sample navigation drawer examples with fragments

- [Example 1](https://guides.codepath.com/android/Fragment-Navigation-Drawer)
- [Example 2](https://www.simplifiedcoding.net/android-navigation-drawer-example-using-fragments/)

Comment: i used your way but the app stopped and the logcat showed this error: Process: com.orion.android.mylawyerdiary, PID: 15511
    java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No view found for id 0x7f0d00aa

Comment: Is this R.id.contentFragment current fragment holder view?

Comment: content fragment is the id of frame layout that is used to load the fragment

Comment: If you want to replace fragment with your current fragment you need to do with listener from activity.

Comment: but i want to replace the fragment on buttons click which is in another fragment so i have to replace it by this code on that previous one fragment only

Comment: it should be extend and not implement in the interface

Comment: can i add a handler instead? because its not working and showing errors

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/128992/discussion-between-mismanc-and-annie).

Answer (score 0):

This is because your current's fragment background is transparent.

This happens when you use:

```
FragmentTransaction.addToBackStack(String)
```

since previous fragment is kept so when you push back you can get back there.

The solution is to specify:

```
android:background="@android:color/white"
```

or any other color you want in your fragment's layout parent tag

Comment: I had used this piece of code and it doesn't have any string  Addhearingnewfrag fragment = new Addhearingnewfrag();
//                FragmentManager fragmentManager = getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager();
//                FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
//                fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.contentFragment, fragment);
//                fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack(null);
//                fragmentTransaction.commit();
//            }
//        });

Comment: you don't need to enter string, addToBackStack(null) could be fine, just the concern is use add fragment rather replace and set your layout background = white

Comment: i used addToBackStack but still the problem is there @Farhan

Comment: did u replace 
fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.contentFragment, fragment); 
with
fragmentTransaction.add(R.id.contentFragment, fragment);?